# How to install Ansible20 via Homebrew on macOS

Tags: macos, ansible, homebrew

I've done this many times up until a couple of months ago.

The steps seem to have changed since versions is now deprecated?

1) `brew tap homebrew/versions`

2) `brew search ansible`

3)  Returns `ansible@2.0` as an option

4) `brew install ansible20`

5) Finally `brew install homebrew/versions/ansible20`

However I am now getting the following response

`Warning: Use ansible20 instead of deprecated homebrew/versions/ansible20
Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/core/ansible20"
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.`

Does `/core/` not have the same formulae? What happened to versions?

Comment: Why do you want to install Ansible 2.0? And why do you want to install Ansible with Homebrew?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are asking? Is there something wrong with using a package on homebrew. 

We need ansible20 for our Trellis install. The above command worked for us for the past few months. But since versions has been deprecated it's no longer an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ansible@2.0` in core, in place of `ansible20`.

Just run `brew install ansible@2.0`.

Excerpt from https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions:

> This tap was deprecated because homebrew/core has started to support multiple versions. All widely used, buildable formulae will be migrated to homebrew/core.
>   Learn more about this migration in the Versions documentation.

Excerpt from http://docs.brew.sh/Versions.html ("the Versions documentation" mentioned above)

> In Homebrew/versions the formula for GCC 6 was named gcc6.rb and began class Gcc6 < Formula. In Homebrew/core this same formula is named gcc@6.rb and begins class GccAT6 < Formula.

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for. Cheers Equal!